# vscode plugin for c++ auto add include header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a visual studio code's plugin for c++ has feature that auto complete/add include header when writing code. Any suggestion?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you are looking for, but the Microsoft C++ extension can suggest folders/headers when you type `#include <` or `#include "`.  There were some bugs with the feature until January of this year when the stability was greatly improved.

Comment: I think by auto add, he meant: When writing `vector<int>...` extension should automatically do `#include <vector>`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there isn't any extension like what you exactly want, but you can create your own desired option without any extension and only using **USER-SNIPPETS**. To do this:
`open visual studio code` > `File` > `Preferences` > `User Snippets` : here you can create a new user snippets file or use an existing one, if you are new you might don't have any hence create a fresh one(make sure it is for c++), then put your desired snippets, here's mine as an example:

```
"Add iostream & string": {
        "prefix": "#include",
        "body": [
          "#include <iostream>",
          "#include <string>",
          ""
        ],
        "description": "Add iostream & string"
}
```

after whenever you type `#inc` in a `.cpp` file a snippet will be shown for you and you can accept that.

but if you mean what  **Deepak Punjabi**  said, considering that c++ has a huge amount of libraries it isn't actually intellectual to do such a thing. searching a huge huge bunch of libraries to just include a header. the feature you are looking for somehow is a compiler feature which some languages like python meet the needs better.

Comment: Some static checkers, including those in gcc and clang do suggestions. But addin it into UI might result in a laggy editor

Comment: Eclipse CDT does it quite effectively. In vscode if you don't know what header to use, you can press F12 while the cursor is in the fonction and it will load the header file.  Not 100% because you might endup in some "internal" header but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Does not find any plugin that supports auto add #include header files. However , there's one plugin `[Include What You Use][1]` may help optimize the include files.

The main goal of include-what-you-use is to remove superfluous #includes. It does this both by figuring out what #includes are not actually needed for this file (for both .cc and .h files), and replacing #includes with forward-declares when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the clangd plugin to automatically include header files and get better code completion.

[vscode-clangd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd)

Comment: can you elaborate? what are the exact relevant capabilities of this extension? what are the conditions for automatic header inclusion to kick in?